# Call to undefined method Magento AttributeMetadataConverter.php

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I used the Migration data tool for migration data from 1.8 tot 2.0.2. The migration was successful. But after that i can't open the customer grid or a order. This is the error.

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend::getAllOptions()
>   in
>   /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php
>   on line 66

The customer data is available in customer_grid_flat.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also experiencing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should find the attributes in the **table eav_attribute**, those need to have **entity_type_id = 1**; **frontend_input = select** or **multiselect**.

Then delete which one of them has **backend_model = null**

do not delete the attribute which has attribute code like **gender, group_id, store_id, website_id**

only delete custom attribute which also have backend_model specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but for anybody googling who doesn't have the 20 minutes of back-tracking to spare, the issue is with an incompatible customer (and/or order) attribute that was inadvertently imported during migration.

I solved this issue by querying the eav_attribute table for all customer attributes with source models matching the ArrayBackend type, then (with some discernment based on naming) deleting them. You can then mark down the attribute ID and delete any corresponding entries in the applicable customer_entity_(x) table, but none existed for me.

I assume you could do the same thing for order attributes by using the appropriate entity_type_id in your query of the eav_attribute table.

Data migration by hand almost seems more palatable, but I'm still giving the Magento tools a chance...